# Fluid border around input+span. Css rendering difference in FF/Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've got a stylized input I'm working on in html/css that achieves the look I'm going for in Firefox, but the elements (input and span) seem to be rendering differently in Chrome. I have yet to test on IE.

The code is available at http://jsfiddle.net/WEZvu/. Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the differences? The two browsers render identically for me.

Comment: The borders render in a way that they don't line up on the input and the span in Chrome and Firefox under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this acceptable? http://jsfiddle.net/WEZvu/1/

Since your border and background-color is applied in the whole "element", putting them on the container seems a better idea.

I'm using Linux right now and no IE to test, but I think the look should be OK...

Comment: I'm embarrassed this didn't occur to me. This is a much cleaner way of achieving the desired effect.